# Suggest user to place apps appwidget on the homescreen

Tags: android, android-appwidget

i have an app on googleplay (MyWords-MyDictionary). After collecting some stats from google analystics i saw that very few is using apps appwidget. I am assuming that people are not aware of the appwidgets existence.. Problem is my apps unique strengt is its appwidget. So somehow i need to suggest user to put the app widget on the homescreen...

What is the right way to do it... How can i make user aware of my widget? It is possible to open the widgetpicker and point out my widget and on click maybe it will be added to the homescreen?

Comment: When user opens your application show a dialog box describing the widget. Make sure you don't annoy the user so it should be displayed 2-3 times so that the user notices it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On splash screen make a textview stating "You have my gratitude for downloading the app but please do try the widget as well."
P.S. you don't have to use fancy language you can also type t hanks but this site won't let me type it like that